# Entity Framework core how to use Case When statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project. I have a query in SQL similar to this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,
            CASE WHEN FromDate < '2020-03-10' THEN '2020-03-10' ELSE FromDate END,
            CASE WHEN ToDate > '2020-03-20' THEN '2020-03-20' ELSE FromDate END) + 1) AS ddd
FROM
    leave_Tbl
```

But I need create this query in EF Core 3.1

I have written this query:

```
var query = _context.Leave_Tbl.Sum(p => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(p.FromDate_DaysLeave, p.ToDate_DaysLeave));
```

But I don't know how to use the `case when` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt3 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt4 = DateTime.Now;
var query = _context.Leave_Tbl.Sum(p => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(dt1 > dt2 ? dt3 : dt4, dt1 > dt2 ? dt3 : dt4));
```

I have just taken these dates for simplicity.